# Physics collision mesh two sided?

Tags: ios, collision-detection, game-physics, scenekit

I want to create a wall that is transparent on one side and opaque of the other, that is easy to do with the mesh being one sided. However, I want to accomplish the same thing on the physic's collision mesh for SceneKit, ie. I want to be able to have an avatar "walk" through the wall from one side and collide with it on the opaque side.

Question, is the physics collision mesh one sided or two sided?

If it is two sided I assume I can change the collision mesh procedurally to be dynamic and not be dynamic based on which side I am currently on?